# Arguments lost when running ssh host sh -c

Tags: shell, ssh

Running `ssh u@h command arguments` works as expected:

```
$ ssh verence@dock df /run
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            6551280  1888   6549392   1% /run
```

If I add a shell on the remote host, the argument seems to be lost:

```
$ ssh verence@dock sh -c 'df /run'
Filesystem      1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev             32730924        0   32730924   0% /dev
tmpfs             6551280     1888    6549392   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1920224544 17109596 1805499128   1% /
...
```

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but didn't find any clues. What is happening here?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Don't think so. Running `ssh u@h sh -c 'echo; df /run'` works as expected, so it doesn't directly seem to be a quoting issue.

Comment: In this case you run `sh -c echo; df /run` on the remote. In your original case you run `sh -c df /run`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ah, right, got it. Thanks.

Comment: Also see the "discussion" part of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1534401/432690). You may find this question useful: [*How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?*](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski indeed, thx.